# find query through floating values

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to figure out a way to query based on two floating values. In my case these are `longitude` and `latitude`.

Currently I'm calculating shortest distance to point A, using Google Matrix API. That again returns me the `longitude` and `latitude` of the shortest distance.

Now I'd like to be able to use that to find the location in my database.

I've tried using `Location.find_by(latitude: value, longitude: value)` and for some reason this works sometimes, but not other times.

Even though I'm copy pasting the values from the database into it. So now I'm trying to figure out a way I can easily figure out which location it has calculated as shortest as this query seems to be inaccurate.

Any ideas on tackling this?

Comment: Wonder who voted this down :/ people should explain their votes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should give this gem a try: https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder

It has some really useful helpers such as:

```
Location.near([40.71, -100.23], 20, :units => :km)
                               # Locations within 20 kilometres of a point
```

Also this gem works really well with Google or other Map Api.

The thing with "find_by" it that it will search for the exact same values. So depending on your rounding, it may not be the exactly same value as the one stored in the database. So if you still want to use that, you should be really careful with the values you get from Google and the ones stored in your DB.

Also you put same value variable in your code:

```
Location.find_by(latitude: value, longitude: value)
```

But perhaps you did not do an exact copy/paste of your code? That should rather be:

```
lat = point_latitude
lng = point_longitude
Location.find_by(latitude: lat, longitude: lng)
```

Comment: I ended up going with using the geocoder way, as I'm already using it. I set the radius of 0.001 which is 1m and it was able to find the location. Weird but it works unlike the find_by which was inaccurate.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are trying to query where both `latitude` and `longitude` are same.

You should try something like:

```
Location.find_by(latitude: lat_value, longitude: long_value)
```

whereas `lat_value` and `long_value` contain the required values against which you want to query.

Comment: they were different values, just used same placeholder